# Allow subscribers to extend a packaged trigger with Process

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, process-builder, isv

I want to call Process instances from an Apex trigger like I know we can do it for Flows.

Here is why: In my `Managed Package` I have a `CustomObject__c` to which users can assign a `Process Builder` process. This process should allow non-coding users to define conditions and actions in a no-code manner.

In such a process the user can define **Conditions** like:

```
CustomField > threshold
```

and **Actions** like Field Updates, Chatter posts, etc.

I know that Process Builder can do this alone but I want to guard and enhance that process by wrapping (packaged) Apex code. So a trigger class should look like this

```
trigger CustomObjects on CustomObject__c (after update) {

    for(CustomObject__c record : records) {
        String processId = record.txt_ProcessId__c;
        Process process = initialize(processId);
        Map<String, Object> output = process.runWith(record);

        postProcessing(record, output);
    }
}
```

and allow me to:

1. Initialize the `Process` for each record
2. Run `Process` for the record
3. the `Process` itself checks the conditions and runs the actions if they apply
4. the `Process` returns with a few ouput params
5. The Trigger code runs some postprocessing code